# bash script variable content in cmd line interpreted as filename by mplayer

Tags: bash, variables, command-line, mplayer, interpretation

I have a script for playing movies through mplayer, for which I am attempting to include automatic conversion of 3D to 2D. Here is the relevant cmd line as it appears in the script

```
mplayer -fs "${g[$i]}" -ss $f "${d%.*}".* -hardframedrop -nocorrect-pts -identify &>> log.txt
```

This does not render to 2D even though "${g[$i]}" has the needed option

```
echo "${g[$i]}"
 -vo gl:stereo=3
```

But if I modify the cmd line to show the option directly, the movie is shown in 2D

```
mplayer -fs -vo gl:stereo=3 -ss $f "${d%.*}".* -hardframedrop -nocorrect-pts -identify &>> log.txt
```

The problem seems to be that mplayer interprets the option as a filename when delivered via ${g[$i]}, thus from log.txt

```
Playing  -vo gl:stereo=3 .
File not found: ' -vo gl:stereo=3 '
Failed to open  -vo gl:stereo=3 .
```

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `" -vo gl:stereo=3 "` which is indeed invalid. You should be passing `"-vo"` followed by `"gl:stereo=3"`. In other words, it should be passed as two separate arguments without the leading and trailing spaces.

The easiest workaround to make this happen is to skip the quotes around `${g[$i]}`:

```
mplayer -fs ${g[$i]} -ss $f "${d%.*}".* -hardframedrop -nocorrect-pts -identify &>> log.txt
```

The more robust workaround would be to store the arguments separately in an array, e.g. `opts=("-vo" "gl:stereo=3")` and using `"${opt[@]}"`, but Bash does not support multidimensional arrays so this may require some deeper changes to your script.